# Umbraco examine/lucene search - shared content?

Tags: lucene, umbraco7

I have a fairly simple Umbraco solution, which uses Lucene for the frontend site search.
The site has the option (via a macro), to include the same text/node, on multiple pages, so they only have to maintain that text one place.

But, as this is "generated" in the frontend, on load, and Lucene indexes the pages, and does not crawl the frontend, these texts are not included in the search.

How could i go about, getting Lucene to include these texts on each page they are included on?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to hook into the indexing events exposed by Examine to parse the fields with the macro in and retrieve the blocks of text from the macro node.

You need to hook into the "GatheringNodeData" event on the relevant indexes in your startup event handler, e.g.

```
ExamineManager.Instance.IndexProviderCollection["IndexName"].GatheringNodeData
             += ExamineEvents_GatheringNodeData;
```

In your function, you can process the field and edit the field, e.g:

```
void ExamineEvents_GatheringNodeData(object sender, IndexingNodeDataEventArgs e)
{
    //check if this is 'Content'
    if (e.IndexType == IndexTypes.Content)
    {
         //access node with e.Node, access Examine fields with e.Fields
    }
}
```